# Adding a content editor web part (which reference a .txt file) will break my list view inside mobile devices

Tags: 2013, development, administration, configuration, mobile-view

I am working on a SharePoint 2013, and i have a team site collection which have the mobile browser view feature enabled. now inside the team site i have around 10 lists which are working well when accessed from mobile devices. except for one list view which i have edited its page (from setting >> Edit Page), and i add a content Editor web part which reference a .txt file. the .txt file have the following HTML:-

```
<img src="/Resources/Matrix.png" alt="Risk Matrix" style="width:854px;height:258px;">
```

[image]

Now the list view page which is referencing the above content editor, will have the image added correctly inside non-mobile devices screens.
but the problem is that when i access the list view from mobile devices i got the error:-

[image]

now if i remove the content editor web part the page will work well inside the mobile screens. so my question is how i can overcome this problem? i am thinking if any of these approaches can be achieved :-

1. either to allow my content editor web part to work on mobile devices. in other words to force the image to be shown inside mobile screens .
2. the other option is if i can force sharepoint to bypass the content editor web part on mobile devices.

seems strange to me as sharepoint 2013 claim that it is mobile supported,, and i am adding a built-in web part of type content editor,, so how come this is not not working on mobile devices ??
Thanks

**EDIT**

now here is the full table which i am rendering as an image:-

[image]

and here is how it will look like on mobile devices when i deactivate the mobile browser view feature:-

[image]

Comment: I would suggest a some CSS - use a media query that checks if the device width is less than say 400px,  then do not display the image, or change the image size so it fits on the screen (width:80%).

Comment: @JasonJames so are you saying if I provide a smaller image it can be shown correctly inside mobile screens... in other words the problem is with the image itself and not with having a content editor web part ??

Comment: Keep the content editor webpart as it as and then deactivate the mobile browser view. Can you share your results then ?

Comment: @GautamSheth please check my edit.. now one note i am testing the mobile view by adding mobile=1 to the end of the URL of the page.

Comment: @JohnG Its possible, if you do try, let me know if it worked.

Comment: @JasonJames before i start testing this , you mean the problem is within the image size itself ?? and not that the content editor web part are not supported on mobile devices ??

Comment: @JohnG I suggested that maybe it will fix your issue, but from what I read online it seems that this is a common issue and resizing the image may not solve the issue, can you not just add the image without using the content editor web part?

Comment: @JasonJames now i tried resizing the image to have 150x150 dimension, but still i am facing the same issue on mobile devices... i even add only the following html `<span></span>` inside the .txt file but still the list view will not be shown on mobile devices.... so in a way or another if any page have a content editor web part, then it will not be accessible on mobile devices regardless of the content !!!! so sharepoint will not  even bypass the content editor web part on mobiel devices it will break the whole page ..

Comment: @johnG please adapt the link for your second picture. It has the same URL like the first one...

Comment: @johnG can you not just insert the picture (from SharePoint) and overwrite the file if the image need to change?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to disable the `Mobile browser view` feature. When this feature is enabled you will face issues related to content editor and script editor webparts rendering on mobile devices such as below.

```
(Some apps, such as Content Editor(script editor), are not supported in mobile view. Tapping on title area can bring up navigation window.)
```

Once you disable this `Mobile browser view` feature, the CEWP webpart will start rendering on the page in mobile devices.

[image]

Comment: but this approach is not acceptable by our customer and i already know that if i disable the mobile browser view i will be able to access the sites from my mobile devices but with a bad user experience ... so  i still want to have the mobile friendly interface for users ,, but not sure how i can fix the content editor web part problem ...

Comment: As long as mobile browser view is activated , the CEWP and Script editor webpart wont render on mobile device. This is a platform limitation. You cant get around this. One option would be modify the CSS to make it responsive and use media queries to make it work - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp. Using CSS media queries, change the height and width of image based on device dimensions https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: but on some pages i added some script editor web parts, and on mobile views those script editors will not be shown, but the renaming of the page components will be shown correctly in a mobile friendly way ... but in my current case when i added the content editor web part the whole list view page breaks.. i was expecting that the content editor web part will not be shown (on other word the image will not be shown) on mobile devices (which is fine to me) ,, but the problem is that the whole page breaks as shown in the picture i provided... did u get my point ?

Comment: hmm, instead of content editor, can try with script editor webpart ? also can check and see what happens when you append `mobile=0`

Comment: now the script editor will not achieve what i am looking for.. now in my case i have around 30 sub-sites, and inside each subsite's list view i have added a content editor web part which reference a shared .txt file,, so if i want to modify the 30 sub-site, i will only change the .txt file and got the effect on all the underlying 30 sub-sites.. so not sure if the script editor will be beneficial to me... i am really confused